# Kubernetes: Can not curl minikube pod

Tags: docker, deployment, kubernetes, minikube

What happened:
I have been following this guidelines: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/minikube/ and I have the "connection refused" issue when trying to curl the application. Here are the steps I did

```
~~> minikube status
minikube: Stopped
cluster: 
kubectl: 
~~> minikube start
Starting local Kubernetes v1.10.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
Getting VM IP address...
Moving files into cluster...
Setting up certs...
Connecting to cluster...
Setting up kubeconfig...
Starting cluster components...
Kubectl is now configured to use the cluster.
Loading cached images from config file.
~~> kubectl run hello-minikube --image=k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.10 --port=9500
deployment.apps/hello-minikube created
~~> kubectl expose deployment hello-minikube --type=NodePort
service/hello-minikube exposed
~~> kubectl get pod
NAME                              READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
hello-minikube-79577c5997-24gt8   1/1       Running   0          39s
~~> curl $(minikube service hello-minikube --url)
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.99.100 port 31779: Connection refused
```

**What I expect to happen:**
When I curl the pod, it should give a proper reply (like in the quickstart: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/minikube/)

minikube logs: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1o2-ebiZTsoCzQNSn_rQSkcuVzOJABmwT2KKzGoUQNiQ/edit

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce this error. Now looking into the cause …

Comment: I like how you have structured this post. Nice!

Answer (score 6):

Not sure where you got the port `9500` from but that's the reason it doesn't work. NGINX serves on port `8080`. This should work (it does for me, at least):

```
$ kubectl expose deployment hello-minikube \
          --type=NodePort \
          --port=8080 --target-port=8080


$ curl $(minikube service hello-minikube --url)

Hostname: hello-minikube-79577c5997-tf49z

Pod Information:
        -no pod information available-

Server values:
        server_version=nginx: 1.13.3 - lua: 10008

Request Information:
        client_address=172.17.0.1
        method=GET
        real path=/
        query=
        request_version=1.1
        request_scheme=http
        request_uri=http://192.168.64.11:8080/

Request Headers:
        accept=*/*
        host=192.168.64.11:32141
        user-agent=curl/7.54.0

Request Body:
        -no body in request-
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help!
I did not think that using a different port would cause such a problem

Comment: You're welcome and please accept this answer as the correct one so that people after you know that it helped you fixing the issue.